# Add conditional value in Linq from switch case

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that select some value. The code is:

```
var query = from c in snd.external_invoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
            join o in snd.invoices on c.idexternal_invoices equals o.id_external_invoice
            select new
                     {
                       c.idexternal_invoices,
                       c.businessname,
                       o.number,
                       c.message,
                       c.price,
                       c.date,
                       c.tipologiaPagamento,
                       c.esitoPagamento,
                       c.iduser
                     };
```

Now i need to select some value in this query based on value in the field c.tipologiaPagamento. In particular, i need to select all the value where c.date it's equal to this switch result:

```
            switch (c.tipologiaPagamento)
            {
                case "1":
                    c.date.AddDays(10);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    c.date.AddDays(10);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(c.date.Year,
                                   c.date.Month,
                                   DateTime.DaysInMonth(c.date.Year,
                                                        c.date.Month));
                    c.date = endOfMonth;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    DateTime nextMonth = c.date.AddMonths(1);
                    DateTime endOfNextMonth = new DateTime(c.date.Year,
                                   c.date.Month,
                                   DateTime.DaysInMonth(c.date.Year,
                                                        c.date.Month));
                    c.date = endOfNextMonth;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

So i need to select in the query the values where c.date is equal to the result of this switch.

How can i do this?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can pass in a complex calculation like ou want easily into a linq expression? Someone can fix me if I'm wrong with this.

What I would do probably, since your calculation depends only on your `tipologiaPagamento` value only, and uses the `date` value only in the calculation, which you have in your current result set anyway, not to bother myself doing that on the SQL side. Simply get all the needed information, and put your switch statement into a `foreach` loop to update the values at the application server level as needed. Probably that'll be able to do the calculation faster than the SQL server, which is not necessarily optimized for data manipulation, but more for data retrieval.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the anonymous types are immutable, hence cannot be post updated.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, you need to create a type for the data to do this. Thanks @IvanStoev

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var query = from c in snd.external_invoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
                        join o in snd.invoices on c.idexternal_invoices equals o.id_external_invoice
                        where c.date== FindDate(c.tipologiaPagamento, c.date)
                        select new
                        {
                            c.idexternal_invoices,
                            c.businessname,
                            o.number,
                            c.message,
                            c.price,
                            c.date,
                            c.tipologiaPagamento,
                            c.esitoPagamento,
                            c.iduser
                        };



  public DateTime FindDate(string tipologiaPagamento, DateTime date)
        {

            DateTime Result = new DateTime();
            switch (tipologiaPagamento)
            {
                case "1":
                    Result = date.AddDays(10);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    Result = date.AddDays(10);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year,
                                   date.Month,
                                   DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year,
                                                        date.Month));
                    date = endOfMonth;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    DateTime nextMonth = date.AddMonths(1);
                    DateTime endOfNextMonth = new DateTime(date.Year,
                                  date.Month,
                                   DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year,
                                                       date.Month));
                    date = endOfNextMonth;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return Result;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not so clear, but very effective:

```
from c in ...
...
select new
  {
   Invoices = c.idexternal_invoices,
   Cdate =   c.tipologiaPagamento == 1? c.date
           : c.tipologiaPagamento == 2? c.date.AddDays(10)
           : c.tipologiaPagamento == 3? new DateTime(2015,9,1)
           :  new DateTime(1970,1,1),
   User = c.iduser
 };
```

...as it can be compiled part of LINQ expression tree instead of executing in C# side.